# vectorise rows of a dataframe, apply vector function, return to original dataframe r

Tags: r, vector

Given the following df:

```
a=c('a','b','c')
b=c(1,2,5)
c=c(2,3,4)
d=c(2,1,6)
df=data.frame(a,b,c,d)

  a b c d
1 a 1 2 2
2 b 2 3 1
3 c 5 4 6
```

I'd like to apply a function that normally takes a vector (and returns a vector) like `cummax` row by row to the columns in position `b` to `d`.

Then, I'd like to have the output back in the df, either as a vector in a new column of the df, or replacing the original data.

I'd like to avoid writing it as a `for` loop that would iterate every row, pull out the content of the cells into a vector, do its thing and put it back.

Is there a more efficient way? I've given the apply family functions a go, but I'm struggling to first get a good way to vectorise content of columns by row and get the right output.

the final output could look something like that (imagining I've applied a cummax() function).

```
    a b c d 
1   a 1 2 2
2   b 2 3 3
3   c 5 5 6
```

or

```
    a b c d output
1   a 1 2 2 (1,2,2)
2   b 2 3 1 (2,3,3)
3   c 5 4 6 (5,5,6)
```

where output is a vector.

Comment: Please post your desired output in your question. What you mean by `4:2` is not clear. Does this mean `cummax` (by row) from column d to column b?

Comment: Indeed it means cummax by row for those columns. I've edited my post as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this would just be a simple `apply` problem that you want to cbind to df:

```
> cbind(df, apply(df[ , 4:2]   # work with columns in reverse order
                     , 1,      # do it row-by-row
                      cummax) )
  a b c d 1 2 3
d a 1 2 2 2 1 6
c b 2 3 1 2 3 6
b c 5 4 6 2 3 6
```

Ouch. Bitten by failing to notice that this would be returned in a column oriented matrix and need to transpose that result; Such a newbie mistake. But it does show the value of having a question with a reproducible dataset I suppose.

```
> cbind(df, t(apply(df[ , 4:2] , 1, cummax) ) )
  a b c d d c b
1 a 1 2 2 2 2 2
2 b 2 3 1 1 3 3
3 c 5 4 6 6 6 6
```

To destructively assign the result to df you would just use:

```
df <-   # .... that code.
```

This does the concatenation with commas (and as a result no longer needs to be transposed:

```
> cbind(df, output=apply(df[ , 4:2] , 1, function(x) paste( cummax(x), collapse=",") ) )
  a b c d output
1 a 1 2 2  2,2,2
2 b 2 3 1  1,3,3
3 c 5 4 6  6,6,6
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the reverse order of the columns, just the original order. His post has been updated to show this.

Comment: That's perfect! I was also getting the column oriented matrix problem. But also I was being silly with `apply` and writing something like `function(x) cummax(x)` now THAT is a rookie mistake...

Comment: One more question actually, If I destructively assigned my output, I'd lose the info in column `a` correct? How could I prevent that? What I'm thinking is something a bit like that `dplyr::mutate` does for example, adding to the df it's working on.

Comment: @Imo the order is a minor detail but indeed might be worth editing so that other people looking at the question don't get lost. However, I'd be curious to know how to stick back the output in the original df, while keeping the column a. Rather than binding two dfs as is shown here. It's not the end of the world for my purpose but I'm curious :)

Comment: I don't understand. I did keep the "a" column. And it would be kept with `df <- cbind(df, t(apply(df[ , 4:2] , 1, cummax) ) )`, and I'm not actually binding 2 dfrms, since the results from `apply` (or `t(apply,))` will be a matrix. If you want a text result then use `paste`.